# Solving cyclic dependencies in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have three classes, say, `A`,`B` and `C`. The basic idea is, the class `A` passes a message to `B` and waits, based on that message `B` passes a message to `C`. Finally, after `C` processes the message, it informs `A` to continue with it's function. Now this forms circle. To reduce the dependencies, I make class `A` to communicate with `B` through `C`, i.e. `C` has a method that passes the message of `A` to `B`. The problem with this approach is that it exposes the interface of `B` to  `A`, which I dont want to happen. my questions is, what is the best way to approach this problem.

To give more context, I am working on a speech recognition system. I started with 2 classes, one to get the recognition results (`A`) another to process the result. Later on I had to break the class that processes the result to two, one to do some pre processing (`B`), like checking how good the result is, and another to process the result (`C`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inversion of control**.

```
class Controller {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    private void injectControll() {
        a.registerListener(b); // a.passTo(b);
        b.registerListener(c);
        c.registerListener(a);
    }
```

Comment: Something like `A.getInstance().registerListener(B.getInstance());` or whatever. Certainly.

Comment: All three now depend on a messaging abstraction, eg listener or observer, which all three implement. This is indirection, also.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` and `C` runs in the same JVM, you can add a method in the message itself so `B` can call that method without having direct access to `A`.

You can also look at the visitor pattern or a message bus.

Answer (score 1):

You can send respective messages between services/classes. But don't block your application till you receive messages. Use callback objects as a mechanism for communication.

1. A sends message to B and pass a call back argument. A will continue without waiting.
2. B send message to C and pass a call back parameter. B will continue without waiting.
3. C process message and send message to A on confirmation through callback.
4. A will process callback notification.